# Improve php get_browser() performance

Tags: php, browscap

We are using `get_browser()` in PHP using `php_browscap.ini` but performance is horrible. We  pass 100 or so user-agents into `get_browser()` per page and it takes over 30 seconds to render the page. We need a performant solution, without storing the actual `get_browser()` results persistently (we only want to store user agents).

We already use memcached, is there a way we can alter `get_browser()` to cache results, or load the entire `php_browscap.ini` into memcached.

Answer (score 2):

Ended up rolling our own solution:

```
    ////
    // This function caches in memcached.
    ////
    public static function get_browser_memcached($user_agent) {
        if(empty(MemcacheConnection::$memcache_connection)) {
            MemcacheConnection::connect();
        }

        $memcache_key = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', sha1($user_agent)) . "_user_agent";
        $memcache_result = MemcacheConnection::get($memcache_key);

        if($memcache_result !== false) {
            return $memcache_result;
        }

        $browser = get_browser($user_agent);

        //Store in Memcached (cached for 7 days)
        MemcacheConnection::set($memcache_key, $browser, 604800);
        return $browser;
    }
```

Comment: What's your hit rate to the cache here?  Hard to tell how unique the browsers are and therefore how worthwhile this approach would be...

Answer (score 0):

I havn't used the  **[browscap-php library](https://github.com/browscap/browscap-php)**, but the the usage is highly recommend by the Browser Capabilities Project. http://browscap.org/

The libary on GitHub should improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm chiming in a little late, but for what it's worth, I'm using the **[browscap-php](https://github.com/browscap/browscap-php)** library (as mentioned by @AbcAeffchen) in one of my projects and I'm happy so far.

A typical lookup (from my own *simple* measurements) takes about 20~30ms on a 1 core 512MB cloud instance (which is pretty much the minimum you can find anywhere). I've opted to cache with Redis and this brings the lookup time down to just a couple of ms... so it's possible to optimize if you really need to.

The convenience alone makes it worth a try.